# Правда ли то, что данное предложение не является односоставным?

Tags: синтаксис, глаголы, сказуемые, односоставное-предложение, двусоставное-предложение

`Почему у зонта заостренный конец(,) и еще 19 тайн повседневных вещей.`

Правда ли то, что, если можно поставить глагол *есть* в качестве сказуемого, то это не односоставное уже предложение?

`Почему у зонта`**`есть`**`заостренный конец...`

Или всë-таки односоставное?

Разбираем первую часть самого верхнего предложения!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Почему у зонта **заостренный конец...***

Это **двусоставное** предложение.

***Конец*** — существительное в И.п., но при  этом предложение **назывным**  считать нельзя. Назывные предложения могут распространяться только **определением**. К тому же там еще вопросительное слово.

Скорее всего, предложение **неполное**, сказуемое можно **восстановить** по контексту:

*Почему у зонта **(есть, имеется)** заостренный конец...*